# How to disable text selection IN <li>

Tags: html, css, text, html-lists, selection

I'm having trouble disabling text selection in a `<li>` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3djn/

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

`user-select` works in `<div>`, but doesn't work in `<li>` content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a combination of `user-select: none` and `cursor: default` works:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3djn/6/)

```
ul li {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

tested on:

- macOS 10.6: latest chome and firefox
- windows 7: latest chrome and firefox, IE9
- android 4.2: latest chrome

Comment: Many thx, also works for Tizen ( -webkit-user-select: none; )